# Rvalue std::string doesn't properly bind to const std::string& or returns SIGSEGV

Tags: c++, string, templates, type-deduction

So as i am programming some functionalities to my game, i came across some problem that i do not understand and i seek an explaination.
So i have implemented a simple event system that allows me to send communicates to different systems in my code. Everything was working fine, until i came to a problem with passing a rvalue std::string to one of my functions, please consider following code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <memory>

enum class GameEvent
{
    SomeEvent,
    OtherEvent
};
class EventManager
{
public:
    template <typename ...Args>
    using EventCallback = std::function<void(Args...)>;

    template <typename ...Args, typename Callback>
    void addSubscriber(const GameEvent& gameEvent, Callback&& callback);

    template <typename ...Args>
    void notify(const GameEvent& gameEvent, Args... args);
private:
    struct ListenerBase
    {
        virtual ~ListenerBase() = default;
    };

    template <typename ...Args>
    struct ListenerWrapper : public ListenerBase
    {
        EventCallback<Args...> callback;

        template <typename Callback>
        ListenerWrapper(Callback&& callback_) : callback(std::forward<Callback>(callback_)) {}
        virtual ~ListenerWrapper() = default;

        void useCallback(Args... args)
        {
            callback(args...);
        }
    };
private:
    std::unordered_map<GameEvent, std::vector<std::shared_ptr<ListenerBase>>> eventSubscribers;
};



template<typename ...Args, typename Callback>
inline void EventManager::addSubscriber(const GameEvent& gameEvent, Callback&& callback)
{
    eventSubscribers[gameEvent].emplace_back(std::make_shared<ListenerWrapper<Args...>>(std::forward<Callback>(callback)));
}

template<typename ...Args>
inline void EventManager::notify(const GameEvent& gameEvent, Args ...args)
{
    auto it = eventSubscribers.find(gameEvent);

    if (it == eventSubscribers.end())
        return;

    for (const auto& callback : it->second)
    {
        auto castedCallback = std::static_pointer_cast<ListenerWrapper<Args...>>(callback);
        castedCallback->useCallback(args...);
    }
}

class SomeClass
{
    public:
    SomeClass(EventManager& em) : em(em) {}

    void doSomething()
    {
        em.notify(GameEvent::SomeEvent, "abc", 6);
    }

    EventManager& em;
};

class SomeListener
{
    public:
    SomeListener(EventManager& em)
    {
        em.addSubscriber<const std::string&, const int&>(GameEvent::SomeEvent,
        [this](const std::string& desc, const int& nr){
            someEventImpl(desc, nr);
        });
    }

    void someEventImpl(const std::string& desc, const int& nr)
    {
        std::cout << "Desc: " << desc << " nr: " << nr << std::endl;
    }
};


int main() {

   EventManager manager;
   SomeListener lstr(manager);
   SomeClass scs(manager);

   scs.doSomething();
   

    return 0;
}
```

especially the line:  `em.notify(GameEvent::SomeEvent, "abc", 6);` in doSomething() function.

So with that plain "abc" string, when i try to run the program and it gets to this event handling function, i get that
`desc` is null according to visual studio compiler, and it throws an exception.

So i thought, that i will try to remove `const&` from the lambda funciton in SomeListener constructor, and from `someEventImpl` function, which came to this:

```
SomeListener(EventManager& em)
    {
        em.addSubscriber<std::string, const int&>(GameEvent::SomeEvent,
        [this](std::string desc, const int& nr){
            someEventImpl(desc, nr);
        });
    }

    void someEventImpl(std::string desc, const int& nr)
    {
        std::cout << "Desc: " << desc << " nr: " << nr << std::endl;
    }
```

which gave me totally different error which was 'write access violation' (or SIGSEGV according to godbolt compiler).

I wonder, why it does not work in any of these cases? And why both of these implementations give different errors? Passing an rvalue int as shown doesn't give any errors and compiles well.

In fact, a fix to this problem is pretty easy. I just have to declare a std::string and pass it to the `eventManager.notify(...)` function like this:

```
void doSomething()
    {
        std::string someString = "abc";
        em.notify(GameEvent::SomeEvent, someString, 6);
    }
```

And it works perfectly.
I just wonder, why doesn't this rvalue string don't bind to const&, why integers do not have such a problem and why i get two different errors. Thanks in advance for explaination.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/3njPsPKKP

Comment: I would scrap this design. You're using polymorphic classes but the polymorphism is completely useless because you need to `std::static_pointer_cast` to make any use of what you're storing in the `EventManager`. This isn't any better than using `std::any`.

Comment: It would be tremendously easier if you just created a separate `std::function` type or something per type of event. This is a use case for static polymorphism and templates, not dynamic polymorphism.

Comment: `callback` is a `std::shared_ptr<ListenerWrapper<const std::string&, const int&>>`, but the cast tries to make it into a `std::shared_ptr<ListenerWrapper<const char*, int>>`.

If you make the downcast to the callback type you actually registered, the error goes away - but as @JanSchultke implied, it'll be easier to make it right without having this runtime polymorphism.

Comment: *"a problem with passing a rvalue std::string to one of my functions"* -- This is what you are asking about, right? So why do we need all that background information about some project you're working on? The project led you to the question, but it is not the question. At best, the project could be mentioned at the **end** of the question for context. However, the scenario should be presented abstractly so that it serves no purpose to mention your project.

Comment: *"especially the line:  `em.notify(GameEvent::SomeEvent, "abc", 6);` in doSomething() function."* -- Good to have a line to focus on, but does it have to be in the `doSomething()` function? What if you called `manager.notify` directly from your `main` function? It looks like this would allow you to eliminate the `SomeClass` class from your example, and simpler example code tends to be better (as long as you don't simplify the problem away). How much code infrastructure could be eliminated from your example code? Can you get it down to, as a goal, one class and one member template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when you're calling `em.notify(GameEvent::SomeEvent, "abc", 6)`, `Args` deduces to `[const char*, int]`.

- the stored type is `ListenerWrapper<std::string const&, int const&>`
- the called type is `ListenerWrapper<Args...> = ListenerWrapper<const char*, int>`

**This is undefined behavior** and UBSan catches this: https://godbolt.org/z/WK4qWj3e1

### The underlying issue

Your design is extremely fragile.
When you `std::static_pointer_cast`, you need to downcast to *exactly* the type you originally stored.
However, you have taken no measures to ensure this.
In its current state, your design is no better than casting to `std::any` and back. Your polymorphism through `ListenerBase` is completely useless.

You need to somehow guarantee that each type of event has a specific, hard-coded callback signature.
Implicit conversions should also work, e.g. `const char* -> std::string` (which breaks your design).

### Solution

This is a rough outline of something you could do:

```cpp
enum class GameEvent {
    SomeEvent,
    OtherEvent
};

// define a callback function type for each event
template <GameEvent Event>
using CallbackType =
  std::conditional_t<Event == GameEvent::SomeEvent, void(std::string_view, int),
  std::conditional_t<Event == GameEvent::OtherEvent, void(int),
  void>>;

// helper type
template <GameEvent Event>
struct Callbacks {
    using type = CallbackType<Event>;
    std::vector<std::function<type>> callbacks;
};
```

```
struct EventManager : Callbacks<GameEvent::SomeEvent>, Callbacks<GameEvent::OtherEvent> {

    template <GameEvent Event, typename F>
    void addSubscriber(F&& callback) {
        Callbacks<Event>::callbacks.emplace_back(std::forward<F>(callback));
    }

    template <GameEvent Event, typename... Args>
    void notify(Args... args) {
        for (auto& f : Callbacks<Event>::callbacks) {
            f(args...);
        }
    }
};
```

This solution is much better because it is type-safe.
In this case, `GameEvent` always needs to be known at compile-time. To be fair, you basically always know which game event you want to add subscribers to, or which events you want to notify, so this isn't really an issue.

#### Usage

You can use such an `EventManager` like:

```cpp
EventManager e;
e.addSubscriber<GameEvent::SomeEvent>([](std::string_view s, int x) {
    // ...
});

e.notify<GameEvent::SomeEvent>("foo", 123);
```

*See [live example at Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bnxd8WxsM)*.

#### Further Notes

Ideally, you would also add proper constraints using `std::invocable` et al. to `addSubscriber` and `notify`. Otherwise, if you mess up any types involved, you would get a compiler error somewhere in `emplace_back` or at the call to `std::function::operator()()`.

Comment: A perhaps simpler variant that would be easier to expand on would be to store the different `vector`s in a `tuple`. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/51b7bKTdh)

Comment: @TedLyngmo yeah, I was not happy with the original version of `get`. With my new design, you don't even need `get` and a bunch of other metaprogramming things become easier, so I think I'll keep that one. E.g. the callback type can be stored in each `Callbacks<Event>::type` etc.

Comment: Yes, that's a very nice solution!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So, if I understand correctly, there's no way to avoid hard-coding each function signature I use? At the moment, when I have a dozen of them, it's not a problem, but what if I had hundreds? Is there any other way I could approach sending events with different arguments?

Comment: @mattsanentush you could avoid it if you went with your present approach or used `std::any`, but then implicit conversions can't possibly work, and you need to know the function signature when downcasting. Realistically, you just need a few extra line of code per type of event. It's not so bad, even if there are hundreds of events. You could also consider creating a separate type for each event so that the function signature is effectively encoded in the constructor of the event. Perhaps macros or code generation might help.

Comment: @TedLyngmo just to clarify, in yours way that you linked, i would have to align the enum values and callbacks stored in tuple? So the order in which they are stored would correspond?

Comment: @mattsanentush Yes, it was a minor change to Jan's initial answer to make it slightly more easy to extend. This current answer is much nicer than that though and is even easier to build upon.